# Why isn't my MovieClip displaying images?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I made an image in Photoshop, and then imported it into Flash CS6. I made it into a MovieClip by pressing "F8" and set the class name and everything, like usual.

However, when I try to add it in the stage as my background image, it won't show up at all. The class name is there in the autocomplete, but nothing shows up? I've verified the image is actually in the Symbol, but again, nothing is showing up. When I run the debugger, I keep getting this error:

`unable to open 'C:\src'.`

I thought it might have something to do with the path from where I imported the image in Flash,  but I don't know how to change it. It's not letting me edit the path. So can someone please tell me what's wrong? I'm absolutely clueless! Thanks for your help! (And yes, I did add the child to the display list -- that's not the issue.)

Edit: I should also note that I'm using Flash-Builder. :) So when I do:

```
var bg:BackgroundBase = new BackgroundBase();
addChild(bg);
```

...that's not working at all, even though it should, and it does for other MovieClips in the swc.

Comment: Probably you have moved the original image file elsewhere, and imported as reference. Check if the image exists in the FLA (open it as an archive instead of opening with Flash).

Comment: How could I go about doing that?

Comment: Try re-importing it, probably Flash messed up with this one. Embedding about equals importing if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up having to embed the image. There's a tutorial on how to do this here:

http://www.streamhead.com/embedding-images/